# why the output of following c program is 16 16 16?

Tags: c

The output of following C program is 16 16 16, According to me output should be 10, as f2=f2+f2=4
now this f2=f2+2 will be 8, now a=a+2.5 which will make it 8+2.5=10.5, so 10 10 10 should get printed. But it is printing 16 16 16.

```
int main(void) {
    int a=2,*f1,*f2;
    f1=f2=&a;
    *f2+=*f2+=a+=2.5;
    printf("\n%d %d %d",a,*f1,*f2);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Your assumptions about the order of evaluation are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In your code fragment:

```
    int a=2,*f1,*f2;
    f1=f2=&a;
    *f2+=*f2+=a+=2.5;
```

Evaluation of the expression `*f2+=*f2+=a+=2.5` results in *undefined behavior* because the same scalar object has its value modified more than once between sequence points. (In this case, the object defined by the variable `a` is modified directly and via `*f2`.)

From C11 **6.5 Expressions** paragraph 2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

Although the side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand occurs after the operands have been evaluated (see C11 **6.5.16 Assignment operators** paragraph 3), the order in which the side effects are applied is undefined.

For the following (valid) example fragment:

```
   int a = 2, b = 10, c = 20;
   printf("before: a=%d b=%d c=%d\n", a, b, c);
   c += b += a += 2;
   printf(" after: a=%d b=%d c=%d\n", a, b, c);
```

the output will be:

```
before: a=2 b=10 c=20
 after: a=4 b=14 c=34
```

The order in which the stored values of `a`, `b` and `c` are modified is undefined, but that doesn't affect the value resulting from each assignment, which is well-defined. The result of each assignment in the full expression `c += b += a += 2` is passed on to the next one in right-to-left order. Each object is modified only once, so there is no undefined behavior in this example.

Answer (score 1):

As `a` is of type `int` floating value typecasted to integer.
Your code is simplified to

```
a = 2//initialization
a += 2; // 4
*f2 += a; // 8
*f2 += *f2; // 16
```

As f1,f2 pointers of `a` o/p is `16`

Comment: Can you explain how this causes the seen output?

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
*f1+=*f2+=a+=2.5;
```

can be split into multiple statement as follows:

```
a = a + 2.5;
*f2 = *f2 + a;
*f1 = *f2 + *f2;
```

Since `f1 = &a` and `f2 = &a`, both refer to the same location in memory. So, the value of `*f1` and `*f2` is always the same as `a`. Finally, since `a` stores an `int`, the first statement evaluates to `4`. So, you have:

```
a = a + 2.5; // a = 2 + 2.5 = 4
*f2 = *f2 + a; // *f2 = 4 + 4 = 8
*f1 = *f2 + *f2; // *f1 = 8 + 8 = 16
```